# Por que não existe "logical XOR" no C++?

Tags: c++, lógica, operadores, bitwise

Por que existe "Bitwise OR", "Bitwise AND" e **"Bitwise XOR"**, se na lógica booleana só existe "Logical OR" e "Logical AND".

Deveria existir o **"Logical XOR"**!

Por exemplo:

```
true  false = true
true  true  = false
false true  = true
false false = false
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Existe sim, olha só, dá o resultado que deseja, ele só não chama *logical XOR* porque já tem um nome mais simples, ele é chamado de *diferente*, porque é isso que ele é, ele dá `true` quando os operandos são diferentes, igual ao *bitwise XOR*, pode testar:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << (true != false) << endl;
    cout << (true != true) << endl;
    cout << (false != true) << endl;
    cout << (false != false) << endl;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/CpoU50). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/hibycrqk-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Operator/Xor.cpp).

Comment: faz sentido! não pensei nisso

Answer (score 0):

Existe sim. Além do operador diferente (`!=`), existe o operador `^` que é o XOR binário (bit a bit).

Você pode utilizá-lo com os valores true e false que vai funcionar, o true é convertido para o número 1 e o false é convertido para o número zero, então você pode realizar o XOR entre eles. Veja esse exemplo:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "true ^ true = " << (true ^ true) << endl;
    cout << "true ^ false = " << (true ^ false) << endl;
    cout << "false ^ true = " << (false ^ true) << endl;
    cout << "false ^ false = " << (false ^ false) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```